# Added new row, doesn't insert into mysql

Tags: php, sql

I'm updating my add post script but now I've a problem inserting things into mysql.

When I use this INSERT INTO code:

```
                    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    $id=$_POST['id'];
                    $title=$_POST['title'];
                    $pic=$_POST['pic'];
                    $youtube=$_POST['youtube'];
                    $cat=$_POST['cat'];
                    $NSFW=$_POST['NSFW'];



                    // insert data to mysql
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO post(id, title, pic, youtube, cat, NSFW)VALUES('$id', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat', '$NSFW')";
                    $result=mysql_query($sql);
                    }
```

I can INSERT things into my mysql, but I've added a new row which is called `add`

So If I add `$add=$_POST['add'];` and I change `$sql`

`$sql = "INSERT INTO post(id, add, title, pic, youtube, cat, NSFW)VALUES('$id', '$add', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat', '$NSFW')";`

This doesn't want to insert anything any more.

**EDIT**
Thank you guys, didn't know about the 'add' function of mysql my bad laughed my self haha:P Didn't know since I'm new to this

Comment: `add` is reserved [mysql word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) escape it with backticks for now, but its better to change it to another name.

Comment: backtick add in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ADD` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to enclose them in backticks.

Like this..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO post(id, `add`, title, pic, youtube, cat, NSFW) VALUES ('$id', '$add', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat', '$NSFW')";
                             ^   ^ //<--- Like that.
```

Comment: thank you guys, didn't know about this function just wanted to keep the row name short haha

Answer (score 0):

`Add` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO post(`id`,`add`,`title`,`pic`,`youtube`,`cat`,`NSFW`)
VALUES ('$id',
        '$add',
        '$title',
        '$pic',
        '$youtube',
        '$cat',
        '$NSFW')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add needs to be prefixed and suffixed with ` to work as column name, otherwise its interpreted as keyword

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO post(id, `add`, title, pic, youtube, cat, NSFW)VALUES('$id', '$add', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat', '$NSFW')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO post(`id`, `add`, `title`, `pic`, `youtube`, `cat`, `NSFW`) VALUES ('$id', '$add', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat', '$NSFW')"
```

will works I hope.